# How to add timestamp conditionally for a checkbox value in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to add a timestamp in the checkbox input field as a value. But its always shows the same value.

How to add a different value ( Blank ) while unchecking?

Here is he HTML Code,

```html
<div class="flex items-center mb-4 newsletter-check">                    
<input type="checkbox" id="newsletter" name="join-my-newsletter" class="form-check" value="Yes">
<label class="form-check-label" for="newsletter">Join my newsletter</label>
</div>
```

I used the javascript

```js
$(function() { // when page loads
  var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
$(".newsletter-check input[type='checkbox']").on("click",function() {
if (this.checked) $("#newsletter").attr('value',  + timeNow );
});
});
```

Comment: try using `val()` instead of `attr()`

Comment: I'm not sure you can check if checkbox is checked with `if (this.checked)`. use this instead of that `if ($(this).prop('checked'))`

Comment: @MdNurullah Do you want the time to update if you uncheck then check the checkbox ? Or do you want to set a different value when the checkbox is unchecked ?

Comment: @Tom , Different value when uncheck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can try this code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".newsletter-check input[type='checkbox']").on("click",function() {
    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    if ($(this).prop('checked')==true){
     $("#newsletter").attr('value', timeNow );
     alert(timeNow);
    }else{
     $("#newsletter").attr('value', '');
    } 
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex items-center mb-4 newsletter-check">                    
<input type="checkbox" id="newsletter" name="join-my-newsletter" class="form-check" value="Yes">
<label class="form-check-label" for="newsletter">Join my newsletter</label>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still value showing when i unchecked. I don't want to pass value when uncheck the checkbox

Comment: I have edited the above code, now it will remove value on unchecking the checkbox.

Comment: perfect.. that is what i was looking for

Comment: @MdNurullah Happy to see that it's solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp gets set **on page load** so it does not update.
You can move the timestamp declaration inside the click event so it gets updated **whenever you trigger the checkbox**.

```js
$(function() { // when page loads
$(".newsletter-check input[type='checkbox']").on("click",function() {
  var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
  console.log(timeNow);

  if (this.checked) $("#newsletter").attr('value',  + timeNow );
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex items-center mb-4 newsletter-check">                    
<input type="checkbox" id="newsletter" name="join-my-newsletter" class="form-check" value="Yes">
<label class="form-check-label" for="newsletter">Join my newsletter</label>
</div>
```